# If the team's past performance predicts their future chances of winning, what is the probability they will be champion?

Tags: probability

> A high school football team has a season record of $11$ wins and $5$ loses. In the playoffs,they must win the next two games to become the champions. If the team's past performance predicts their future chances of winning, then the probability that they will be champion is?

**My work:**

They won eleven times and lost five times, meaning sixteen games were played. They must win the next two games, meaning in total, eighteen will be played, therefore they must win $\frac{13}{18}$ games. Multiply $18$ by the probability $x$ that results in $18x \ge 13$, so $\frac{13}{18}=0.722$.

The answer is $0.722$.

Answer (score 1):

What you computed is just the ratio of won matches IF they win the next two matches.

You are supposed to understand the problem this way : each game, the team has a probability of $\frac{11}{16}$ to win, independently of other results.

So the probability to win the next two matches is $\left(\frac{11}{16}\right)^2$.